# Angular2 - formData values are passed as null to HTTP POST

Tags: angular, http, typescript, post, angular2-forms

I post my data to service in postman it works fine. But when I call the service in HTTP post request, it shows success in console but formData goes as null and nothing is saved on the server.

Any help would be appreciated. My code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Headers, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Component({
  selector: 'login-page',
  templateUrl: './add.html'
})
export class ConfigComponent {
constructor(private http:Http) {
    this.news = {
      'newstitle': 'Test Title',
      'newsdescription': 'Test',
      'newstype': 'Test',
      'priority': 'Test',
      'place': 'Test',
      'publishedon': 'Test',
      'publishedby': 'Test',
      'websiteurl': 'Test',
      'contactpersonname': 'Test',
      'mobile1': 'Test',
      'mobile2': 'Test',
      'email': 'Test',
      'display': 'Test',     
      'rating': 'Test'
    };
  }

  onSubmit() {
    let formData:FormData = new FormData(this.news);
    console.log(this.news);
    let headers = new Headers({'encrypt': 'multipart/form-data'});
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });  
    this.http.post('SERVICE URL', formData, options)
        .subscribe(
            data => console.log(data),
            error => console.log(error)
        );
  }
  }
```

**Add.html**

```
<h2>ADD CONFIGS</h2>
  <div class="row">
  <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #heroForm="ngForm">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
      <label for="newstitle">NEWS TITLE:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="news.newstitle" id="newstitle" name="newstitle"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
      <label for="newsdescription">NEWS DESCRIPTION:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="news.newsdescription" id="newsdescription" name="newsdescription"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
      <label for="newstype">NEWS TYPE:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="news.newstype" id="newstype" name="newstype"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
      <label for="priority">PRIORITY:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="news.priority" id="priority" name="priority"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
      <label for="place">PLACE:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="news.place" id="place" name="place"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
      <label for="publishedon">PUBLISHED ON:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="news.publishedon" id="publishedon" name="publishedon"/>
    </div>                

    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
      <label for="publishedby">PUBLISHED BY:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="news.publishedby" id="publishedby" name="publishedby"/>
    </div>                

    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
      <label for="websiteurl">WEBSITE URL:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="news.websiteurl" id="websiteurl" name="websiteurl"/>
    </div>                

    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
      <label for="contactpersonname">CONTACT PERSON NAME:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="news.contactpersonname" id="contactpersonname" name="contactpersonname"/>
    </div>                

    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
      <label for="mobile1">MOBILE 1:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="news.mobile1" id="mobile1" name="mobile1"/>
    </div>                

    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
      <label for="mobile2">MOBILE 2:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="news.mobile2" id="mobile2" name="mobile2"/>
    </div>                                    

    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
      <label for="email">EMAIL:</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="news.email" id="email" name="email"/>
    </div>                                    

    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
      <label for="status">STATUS:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="news.status" id="status" name="status"/>
    </div>                                    

    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
      <label for="display">DISPLAY:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="news.display" id="display" name="display"/>
    </div>                                    

    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
      <label for="rating">RATING:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="news.rating" id="rating" name="rating"/>
    </div>                                    

    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
            <label for="usr">City Image:</label>
            <img width="50px" height="50px" id="cimage">
            <input type="file" (change)="fileChange($event)" placeholder="Upload file">
    </div>       

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add</button>

  </form>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: [`FormData` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) expects a form element. Why are you passing an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**APPEND FORM VALUES (WITH FILE) TO FORMDATA IN ANGULAR2.**

Actually someone had posted answer to my question, credit actually goes to him, I made some modification in appending the object to form data to get it working. 
People can append the form data directly or iterate over the object to add values to formData. 
Below is my working code:

**Component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Headers, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Component({
  selector: 'login-page',
  templateUrl: './add.html'
})
export class ConfigComponent {
news;
fileList;
constructor(private http:Http) {
    this.news = {
      'newstitle': 'Test Title',
      'newsdescription': 'Test Title',
      'newstype': 'Test Title',
      'priority': 'Test Title',
      'place': 'Test Title',
      'publishedon': 'Test Title',
      'publishedby': 'Test Title',
      'websiteurl': 'Test Title',
      'contactpersonname': 'Test Title',
      'mobile1': 'Test Title',
      'mobile2': 'Test Title',
      'email': 'Test Title',
      'status': 'Test Title', 
      'display': 'Test Title',     
      'rating': 'Test Title'
    };
  }

      fileChange(event) {
        this.fileList = event.target.files;
      }

  onSubmit() {
    let formData:FormData = new FormData();

    formData.append('newstitle', this.news.newstitle);
    formData.append('newsdescription', this.news.newsdescription);
    formData.append('newstype', this.news.newstype);
    formData.append('priority', this.news.priority);
    formData.append('place', this.news.place);
    formData.append('publishedon', this.news.newstitlpublishedone);
    formData.append('publishedby', this.news.publishedby);
    formData.append('websiteurl', this.news.websiteurl);
    formData.append('contactpersonname', this.news.contactpersonname);
    formData.append('mobile1', this.news.mobile1);
    formData.append('mobile2', this.news.mobile2);
    formData.append('email', this.news.email);
    formData.append('status', this.news.status);
    formData.append('display', this.news.display);
    formData.append('rating', this.news.rating);

    if(this.fileList.length > 0){
      for (var x = 0;  x < this.fileList.length; x++) {
      let file: File = this.fileList[x];
      formData.append('fileData', file, file.name);
      }
      let headers = new Headers({'encrypt': 'multipart/form-data'});
      let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });  
      this.http.post('SERVICE URL', formData, options)
        .subscribe(
            data => console.log(data),
            error => console.log(error)
        );
    } else {
      let headers = new Headers({'encrypt': 'multipart/form-data'});
      let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });  
      this.http.post('SERVICE URL', formData, options)
        .subscribe(
            data => console.log(data),
            error => console.log(error)
        );
    }
  }
}
```

**ADD.html**

```
<h2>ADD CONFIGS</h2>
  <div class="row">
  <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #heroForm="ngForm">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
      <label for="newstitle">NEWS TITLE:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="news.newstitle" id="newstitle" name="newstitle"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
      <label for="newsdescription">NEWS DESCRIPTION:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="news.newsdescription" id="newsdescription" name="newsdescription"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
      <label for="newstype">NEWS TYPE:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="news.newstype" id="newstype" name="newstype"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
      <label for="priority">PRIORITY:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="news.priority" id="priority" name="priority"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
      <label for="place">PLACE:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="news.place" id="place" name="place"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
      <label for="publishedon">PUBLISHED ON:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="news.publishedon" id="publishedon" name="publishedon"/>
    </div>                

    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
      <label for="publishedby">PUBLISHED BY:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="news.publishedby" id="publishedby" name="publishedby"/>
    </div>                

    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
      <label for="websiteurl">WEBSITE URL:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="news.websiteurl" id="websiteurl" name="websiteurl"/>
    </div>                

    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
      <label for="contactpersonname">CONTACT PERSON NAME:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="news.contactpersonname" id="contactpersonname" name="contactpersonname"/>
    </div>                

    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
      <label for="mobile1">MOBILE 1:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="news.mobile1" id="mobile1" name="mobile1"/>
    </div>                

    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
      <label for="mobile2">MOBILE 2:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="news.mobile2" id="mobile2" name="mobile2"/>
    </div>                                    

    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
      <label for="email">EMAIL:</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="news.email" id="email" name="email"/>
    </div>                                    

    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
      <label for="status">STATUS:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="news.status" id="status" name="status"/>
    </div>                                    

    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
      <label for="display">DISPLAY:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="news.display" id="display" name="display"/>
    </div>                                    

    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
      <label for="rating">RATING:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="news.rating" id="rating" name="rating"/>
    </div>                                    

    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
            <label for="usr">City Image:</label>
            <img width="50px" height="50px" id="cimage">
            <input type="file" id="newsimg" name="newsimg" multiple="true" (change)="fileChange($event)">
    </div>             

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add</button>

  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you meet this kind of situation, you should check if your `formData` was created correctly. A simple way to do this is:

`console.log(formData.get('newstitle')) // check 'newstitle' field`

You can also check other fields in `formData` object.

@Jamshed's answer should be correct. But if you need to pass `user_name` and `password` through `Headers`, you can create `options` like this:

```
  createAuthorizationHeader(headers: Headers, name: string, pw: string) {
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' +
      btoa(`${name}:${pw}`)); 
  }
  createOptions(name: string, pw: string) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers, name, pw);
    // headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');  // <--- we can do post without this item.
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return options;
  }
```

Then a `post` can be done like this:

```
private imageUrl = 'http://192.168.201.211:8024/images/';
post(formData: FormData, user: string, pw: string): Promise<MyForm> {
    let options = this.createOptions(user, pw);
    console.log('we will have a post!');
    return this.http.post(this.imageUrl, formData, options)
                    .toPromise()
                    .then(res => res.json() as MyForm)
                    .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```